# How to handle share location functionality of browser in selenium web driver

Tags: java, browser, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Now i am working in a project which contain google map or geo location API. When we click on map it show browser Share location pop up but using selenium web driver i am not able to click on it. And on more thing all browser contain different kind of pop up or slide down for this Share Location. Please provide any solution to handle browser funcationality using selenium or third party tool.

Thanks a lot..!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Sikuli IDE: 
http://www.sikuli.org/
It works with graphical user interface using screenshot images.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Sikuli-Webdriver instead of using Webdriver.You can find more details here at [Link](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver)

Answer (score 0):

By using Screen and Pattern class:- (just add sikuli jar in your project or Add sikuliAPI maven dependencies{if it's maven based} in your project):-

Screen screen=new Screen();

Pattern img1=new Pattern("C:\Selenium Webdriver\Sikuli_Jar\location.png");

screen.click(img1);

*where C:\Selenium Webdriver\Sikuli_Jar\location.png PATH OF SHARELOCATION popup image.